# SNAT iptables does not work when package is encapsulated in esp transport mode

Tags: iptables, nat, ipsec

I have the following setup, involving one host and a docker container.

- On the host, I am setting up an ipsec tunnel connection to a remote gateway.
- In the docker container running on the host, I setup a transport mode ipsec connection to another address that is only reachable via the ipsec tunnel set up previously.

To make sure that every package from the docker-container is routed via the ipsec tunnel, I used iptables like so:

```
sudo ip6tables -j SNAT -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1  -d <vpnSubnet> -s <dockerip> --to-source <virtualip>
sudo ip6tables -j DNAT -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -d <virtualip> -s <vpnsubnet> --to-destination <dockerip>
```

The SNAT rule works before I setup the `xfrm transport mode` connection in the docker. After that, I see a package from the `<dockerip>` to the address in `<vpnsubnet>` on the `docker0` interface, but not anymore on my wireless interface. If I add a `log` iptables rule like so:

```
sudo ip6tables -j LOG -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1  -d <vpnSubnet> -s <dockerip> --log-prefix " [>] Vincent SNAT match"
```

this log trigger before I set up the `ip xfrm` tunnel in the docker-container, but not after. **How to I make sure that the SNAT rule triggers even if there is an ipsec transport mode setup in the docker-container**?

The `ip xfrm` output (from within the docker container, after setting up the transport mode tunnel) looks like follows (shortened for brevity):
**ip xfrm state**

```
src <tunnel-ip> dst <docker-container>
        proto esp spi 0x0000385c reqid 101 mode transport
        replay-window 4 
        auth-trunc hmac(md5) <auth-key> 96
        enc cbc(aes) <enc-key>
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
        sel src ::/0 dst ::/0 
src <docker-container> dst <tunnel-ip>
        proto esp spi 0x8bc04e63 reqid 100 mode transport
        replay-window 4 
        auth-trunc hmac(md5) <auth-key> 96
        enc cbc(aes) <enc-key>
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0xb, bitmap 0x00000000
        sel src ::/0 dst ::/0
```

**ip xfrm policy**

```
src <tunnel-ip> dst <docker-container>
        dir in priority 0 ptype main flag localok
        mark 0/0xffffffff 
        tmpl src :: dst ::
                proto esp spi 0x0000385c reqid 101 mode transport
src <docker-container> dst <tunnel-ip>
        dir out priority 0 ptype main flag localok
        mark 0/0xffffffff 
        tmpl src :: dst ::
                proto esp spi 0x8bc04e63 reqid 100 mode transport
```

Comment: Is `<docker-container>` the same as `<dockerip>` or is there another NAT involved? Could you provide details on the policies and SAs on the host? Did you try without NAT (i.e. with a traffic selector on the host that includes `<dockerip>`)?